# functions definitions are not permitted in this context

Tags: function, matlab

I have a problem with a file. I'm trying to run a `Example.m` in a cluster with functions, but when I run the program appears an error: `"Functions definitions are not permitted in this context"`. The functions are definied in the same file and the main function is called like my `Example.m`.

Greetings and I look forward to your answers...

Comment: In the future, posting your code could help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to tell were your problem lies without code, but I found this in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/87884) on the mathworks news reader:

- script files cannot contain extra functions at the bottom like function files do.
- The first function in a function file should have the same name as the file.

Comment: then maybe it's because of the first item? Defining functions in your script file where they are not allowed?

Comment: Well...Thank you for your response,it doesn´t let me use the function sentence,the second option is not problem because it has the same name...i run my script in the cluster with: matlab -nodisplay -nosplash <archivo.m> salida.out.

Comment: @user1073039 Oh! Then your stdin is kind of trated like a skript - there are no functions allowed. You could instead do `echo archivo | matlab -nodisplay -nosplash > salida.out`. This calls it as function and not as script.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!when the cluster is not busy i will try it and will tell you the result.

Comment: Thank you very much glglgl!!!your help have been useful, that was the problem!! Greetings!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is the first executable line of your `Example.m` the function definition line

```
function out = Example( in )
% body of Example
```

If not, MATLAB is interpreting it as a script. See also `help script` and `help function`.